# How to write SSL Virtual Hosts for www and non www domains for httpd server?

Tags: apache, ssl, redirect, httpd.conf, lets-encrypt

I have generated certificates for my 2 domains **www.example.com** and **example.com**

And here are the **.conf** files for both HTTP and HTTPS protocols:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/funapps
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =www.example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=temp]
</VirtualHost>
```

And in a different file:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/funapps
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Now, this happens:

If I visit http://example.com or https://www.example.com, I'm redirected to https://example.com and https://www.example.com respectively. But as you see, I've provided certificate for **www.example.com** only, the browser shows security warning for non www domain.

So basically, I want to know what option would be better to handle 2 certificates for these 2 domains?

1. Adding IF / ELSE condition for SSL certificate file in same HTTPS virtual host section (I don't know how to do this) OR
2. Specifying 2 different HTTPS virtual hosts containing their respective certificates?

Answer (score 1):

Solution 2 is how we implement SSL virtual hosting. I don't have any idea how you could implement solution 1, I believe it's impossible.